# Assertion error on Dijkstra algorithm implementation on python

Tags: python, shortest-path, dijkstra

I have this python file in which I implemented dijkstra's algorithm iteratively. Graphs are given in adjacency matrix format.

The thing is that in the last case of the test block this is the expected result: **[13.0, 10.0, 14.0, 0.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0]**
and this is the result I'm getting: **[13.0, 10.0, 18.0, 0.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0]**

I don't have any errors in the rest of the cases, that's the only weird case I get.

Any ideas on why is this?

Here's the code:

```
from time import time
from math import inf
import math


# function to get the node with the minimum distance in shortest_path_list
# that hasn't been visited
def min_dist_node(graph, visited, sp_list, current_node):
    dist = inf
    node = 0
    for i in range(0, len(graph)):
        if i != current_node and not math.isinf(graph[current_node][i]) and dist > graph[current_node][i] and not visited[i]:
            dist = graph[current_node][i]
            node = i
    return node



# Dijkstra's algorithm
def Dijkstra (graph, initial):
    sp_list = []
    visited = [False]*len(graph)
    
    for node in range(0, len(graph)):
        sp_list.append(graph[initial][node])
        
    sp_list[initial] = 0.0
    visited[initial] = True
    current_node = initial
    
    while False in visited:
        current_node = min_dist_node(graph, visited, sp_list, current_node)
        visited[current_node] = True
        
        for node in range(0, len(graph)):
            if sp_list[node] > sp_list[current_node] + graph[current_node][node]:
                sp_list[node] = sp_list[current_node] + graph[current_node][node]
    return sp_list


    
    


def test():
   
    g0 =  [[0.0, 5.0, 1.0, inf],
          [5.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0],
          [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 10.0],
          [inf, 2.0, 10.0, 0.0]]
    
    assert Dijkstra(g0, 3) == [4.0, 2.0, 3.0, 0.0]
 
    
    g1 =  [[0.0, 2.0],
           [2.0, 0.0]]
    
    assert Dijkstra(g1,0) == [0.0,2.0]

    
    g2 = [[0.0, 5.0, 3.0],
          [5.0, 0.0, inf],
          [3.0, inf, 0.0]]
    
    assert Dijkstra(g2, 1) == [5.0, 0.0, 8.0]

        
     
    g3 = [[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0],
          [1.0, 0.0, inf, inf, 8.0],
          [2.0, inf, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0],
          [3.0, inf, 2.0, 0.0, 5.0],
          [4.0, 8.0, 2.0, 5.0, 0.0]]
    
    assert Dijkstra(g3, 3) == [3.0, 4.0, 2.0, 0.0, 4.0]

        
    g4 = [[0.0, 6.0, 2.0, 5.0],
          [6.0, 0.0, 4.0, inf],
          [2.0, 4.0, 0.0, 2.0],
          [5.0, inf, 2.0, 0.0]]
    
    assert Dijkstra(g4, 3) == [4.0, 6.0, 2.0, 0.0]
   
    
    g5 = [[0.0, 10.0, 1.0, inf, inf, inf],
          [10.0, 0.0, inf, 5.0, 4.0, inf],
          [1.0, inf, 0.0, 8.0, 2.0, 3.0],
          [inf, 5.0, 8.0, 0.0, inf, 2.0],
          [inf, 4.0, 2.0, inf, 0.0, inf],
          [inf, inf, 3.0, 2.0, inf, 0.0]]
    
    assert Dijkstra(g5, 0) == [0.0, 7.0, 1.0, 6.0, 3.0, 4.0]

    
    
    g6 = [[0.0, 3.0, 1.0, inf, inf, inf, inf],
          [3.0, 0.0, 8.0, 10.0, 5.0, inf, inf],
          [1.0, 8.0, 0.0, inf, inf, inf, inf],
          [inf, 10.0, inf, 0.0, 6.0, inf, 9.0],
          [inf, 5.0, inf, 6.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0],
          [inf, inf, inf, inf, 1.0, 0.0, 4.0],
          [inf,inf,inf, 9.0, 2.0, 4.0, 0.0]]
    
    print(Dijkstra(g6, 3))
    assert Dijkstra(g6, 3)  == [13.0, 10.0, 14.0, 0.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0]

start_time = time()
test()
elapsed_time = time() - start_time   
print("Elapsed time: %0.10f seconds." % elapsed_time)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update! I found a way of solving without using priority queues. In the min_dist_node function if we put dist >= graph[initial][i] we'll consider first all distances (from the initial node) non equal to inf and then all the inf ones.

I think this is the right way, if anyone does see some mistake let me know!

This is how all the algorith looks like now:

```
from time import time
from math import inf


# function to get the node with the minimum distance in shortest_path_list
# that hasn't been visited
def min_dist_node(graph, visited, sp_list, initial):
    dist = inf
    node = 0
    for i in range(0, len(graph)):
        if i != initial and dist >= graph[initial][i] and not visited[i]:
            dist = graph[initial][i]
            node = i
    return node


# Dijkstra's algorithm
def Dijkstra (graph, initial):
    sp_list = []
    visited = [False]*len(graph)
    
    for node in range(0, len(graph)):
        sp_list.append(graph[initial][node])
        
    visited[initial] = True
    
    while False in visited:
        current_node = min_dist_node(graph, visited, sp_list, initial)
        visited[current_node] = True
        
        for node in range(0, len(graph)):
            if sp_list[node] > sp_list[current_node] + graph[current_node][node]:
                sp_list[node] = sp_list[current_node] + graph[current_node][node]
    return sp_list


def test():
   
    g0 =  [[0.0, 5.0, 1.0, inf],
          [5.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0],
          [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 10.0],
          [inf, 2.0, 10.0, 0.0]]
    
    assert Dijkstra(g0, 3) == [4.0, 2.0, 3.0, 0.0]
 
    
    g1 =  [[0.0, 2.0],
           [2.0, 0.0]]
    
    assert Dijkstra(g1,0) == [0.0,2.0]

    
    g2 = [[0.0, 5.0, 3.0],
          [5.0, 0.0, inf],
          [3.0, inf, 0.0]]
    
    assert Dijkstra(g2, 1) == [5.0, 0.0, 8.0]

        
     
    g3 = [[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0],
          [1.0, 0.0, inf, inf, 8.0],
          [2.0, inf, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0],
          [3.0, inf, 2.0, 0.0, 5.0],
          [4.0, 8.0, 2.0, 5.0, 0.0]]
    
    assert Dijkstra(g3, 3) == [3.0, 4.0, 2.0, 0.0, 4.0]

        
    g4 = [[0.0, 6.0, 2.0, 5.0],
          [6.0, 0.0, 4.0, inf],
          [2.0, 4.0, 0.0, 2.0],
          [5.0, inf, 2.0, 0.0]]
    
    assert Dijkstra(g4, 3) == [4.0, 6.0, 2.0, 0.0]
   
    
    g5 = [[0.0, 10.0, 1.0, inf, inf, inf],
          [10.0, 0.0, inf, 5.0, 4.0, inf],
          [1.0, inf, 0.0, 8.0, 2.0, 3.0],
          [inf, 5.0, 8.0, 0.0, inf, 2.0],
          [inf, 4.0, 2.0, inf, 0.0, inf],
          [inf, inf, 3.0, 2.0, inf, 0.0]]
    
    assert Dijkstra(g5, 0) == [0.0, 7.0, 1.0, 6.0, 3.0, 4.0]

    
    
    g6 = [[0.0, 3.0, 1.0, inf, inf, inf, inf],
          [3.0, 0.0, 8.0, 10.0, 5.0, inf, inf],
          [1.0, 8.0, 0.0, inf, inf, inf, inf],
          [inf, 10.0, inf, 0.0, 6.0, inf, 9.0],
          [inf, 5.0, inf, 6.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0],
          [inf, inf, inf, inf, 1.0, 0.0, 4.0],
          [inf,inf,inf, 9.0, 2.0, 4.0, 0.0]]
    
    print(Dijkstra(g6, 3))
    assert Dijkstra(g6, 3)  == [13.0, 10.0, 14.0, 0.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0]

start_time = time()
test()
elapsed_time = time() - start_time   
print("Elapsed time: %0.10f seconds." % elapsed_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a flaw in the logic.
In each iteration, instead of picking up the node which is currently unvisited and at **least distance to the source node (initial)**, you are picking the node which is unvisited and **nearest to the current_node** (which gets updated in every iteration).
Due to this, 0th index node is getting visited but it's distances are not getting updated, and thus the shortest paths going through that nodes are also not getting updated.

Let's do a dry run of your code with the failing test case:

Initial variables:

```
graph:[[0.0, 3.0, 1.0, inf, inf, inf, inf],
      [3.0, 0.0, 8.0, 10.0, 5.0, inf, inf],
      [1.0, 8.0, 0.0, inf, inf, inf, inf],
      [inf, 10.0, inf, 0.0, 6.0, inf, 9.0],
      [inf, 5.0, inf, 6.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0],
      [inf, inf, inf, inf, 1.0, 0.0, 4.0],
      [inf,inf,inf, 9.0, 2.0, 4.0, 0.0]]
visited: [False, False, False, True, False, False, False]
sp_list: [inf, 10, inf, 0, 6, inf, 9]
current_node: 3 (zero indexing)
```

1st Iteration:

```
current_node: 4
sp_list: [inf, 10, inf, 0, 6, 7, 8]
visited: [False, False, False, True, True, False, False]
```

2nd Iteration:

```
current_node: 5 // Node with shortest distance from node 4 instead of node 3.
sp_list: [inf, 10, inf, 0, 6, 7, 8]
visited: [False, False, False, True, True, True, False]
```

3rd Iteration:

```
current_node: 6 // node closest to node 5 which is unvisited
sp_list: [inf, 10, inf, 0, 6, 7, 8]
visited: [False, False, False, True, True, True, True]
```

4th Iteration:

> Here is where the problem occurs. If you observe, all the neighbors of
> node 6 are visited (node 3, node 4 and node 5). So, in this case, the
> function min_dist_node will return the default value of node, which is
> 0. But sp_list[0] = inf!, so, the sp_list entries for nodes connected to 0th node will not be updated.

Thus:

```
current_node: 0
sp_list: [inf, 10, inf, 0, 6, 7, 8]
visited: [True, False,False, True, True, True, True]
```

5th Iteration:

```
current_node: 2 // node unvisited and closest to 0th node
sp_list: [inf, 10, inf, 0, 6, 7, 8] // same issue as in iteration 4
visited: [True, False,True, True, True, True, True]
```

6th Iteration:

```
current_node: 1
sp_list: [13, 10, 18, 0, 6,7,8] // The edge 1 -> 2 will be considered
visited: [True, True ,True, True, True, True, True]
```

Thus the loop will end as all nodes have been visited.

So, the solution lies in **choosing the next closest node to the initial node** instead of the current node. This can be done by storing the node distances in a priority queue.

For implementation of the algorithm, you can refer to [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-greedy-algo-7/)

Comment: I've been trying but I don't understand how can I handle the inf distances. In my min_distance_node function there comes a moment in where I only have nodes not adjacent to my initial node, which have inf distance. Once I finished with the adjacent nodes how can I start with the not adjacent ones?

Comment: You need to modify your approach a little bit.  In each iteration, you need to pick the node which is unvisited and closest to the source node. That node need not be directly connected to the source. 
There are various ways to do this. One of them is that you can use a priority queue (basically a min-heap). Initially, push the source into the queue. In each iteration, pop the node from the queue, mark it as visited, and calculate the distances of the node adjacent to this node from the source node, and push these adjacent nodes into the queue. 
A google search would help you a lot here.

Comment: Okey, I’ll try this. Thank you so much!!

Comment: No problem. Please upvote and mark as correct answer if helpful :)